# Android high CPU usage with handler()

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-handler

I am using a handler for changing my image view :

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {  
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
            while (true) {  
                if (isContinue) {                           
                    viewHandler.sendEmptyMessage(atomicInteger.get());  
                    atomicOption();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }).start();
```

---

```
private final Handler viewHandler = new Handler() {  

    @Override  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
        adViewPager.setCurrentItem(msg.what);  
        super.handleMessage(msg);  
    }  

};
```

My app used over 50% or 30% of CPU !! when I delete my handler this app used 0% of CPU. But I don't know another method to update GUI..

Comment: you have a tight loop in your thread,  sleep that thread from time to time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Handler` and `Runnable` to start a thread and update your view.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        ...... // do your operation
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, time);//sleep some time after this operation
    }
};

handler.post(runnable);//start the thread
```

Because the highest FPS in android is 60, you don't need to update the GUI all the time.

Comment: I am using a loop because I have a ViewPager that it works like a image slider show for different images.